# Security Measures For Applications Which Deal With Users Private Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am currently working on an ASP.NET 3.5 and C# web application which deals with users private information like SSN numbers. What are some of the security measures which I need to take from an application development stand point to feel safe?

Comment: You might get answers to this question for a server admin point of view by posting your question to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure your application you will need to understand the threats it will face and then develop appropriate mitigation techniques. A good place to start would be by creating a **threat model**.

Have a look at some of these resources:

- [How To: Create a Threat Model for a Web Application at Design Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647894.aspx)
- [Web Application Exploits and Defenses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647894.aspx)
- [Web Security: Are You Part Of The Problem?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/14/web-security-primer-are-you-part-of-the-problem/)
- [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

If you will require sensible information from user by a web form it should be protected by SSL (https url). This help you to secure the communication channel between the browser and your server.

You shouldn't store on your database private and sensible information unless it's strictly necessary and if you have to do it of course you have to store it encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, besides the obvious issue of using encryption, I've been told that it's a good practice to avoid having the user's state as part of a class, especially in an external code library.

Eg: Instead of this:

> public class secretClass()
>   public sub new(ssn as string)
>   _ssn = ssn
>   end sub
>   public function getMedicalHistory() as DataSet
>    ' Get private information
>   End Function
>   End Class

Use this:

> public class secretClass()
>   public sub new()
>   End Sub
>   Public Function getMedicalHistory(p_ssn as string) as DataSet
>   ' Get private information
>   End Function
>   End Class

By doing this, you make it more difficult for a malicious hacker to steal private information by somehow gaining control of the `secretClass` object.

Answer (score 1):

Disable remote logon to your database, use several code analysis tools (code coverage and static analyzers), force strong password requirements for logging into the systems, encrypt all data with at least an SHA-1 encryption scheme;  MD5 is found to be far too weak according to government requirements.